# Is $\big\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 :\ \forall t \in [1,\infty)\bullet x_1 + e^{-t}x_2 + e^{-2t}x_3 \leq 1.1\big\}$ a convex polyhedron?

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra

A *convex polyhedron* is a set $S$ that satisfies $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n :\ Ax\preceq b,\ Cx = d\}$ for some positive integers $m, n, p \in \{1,2,\dots\}$, some matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$, and some vectors $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}^p$. (We write $v\preceq w$ for $v_1\leq w_1,\ v_2\leq w_2,\ \dots,\ v_q\leq w_q$ whenever $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^q$ are vectors, for some $q \in \{1,2,\dots\}$.)

Consider the following set. $S := \big\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 :\ \forall t \in [1,\infty)\bullet x_1 + e^{-t}x_2 + e^{-2t}x_3 \leq 1.1\big\}$. Is $S$ a convex polyhedron?

---

Following is my attempt at solving this problem.

I represented $S$ as a union $S = S_{000}\cup S_{001}\cup S_{010}\cup\cdots \cup S_{111}$, where for every $\xi \in \{000,001,010,\dots,111\}$, $S_\xi := S\cap T_\xi$, with
$$
\begin{align*}
T_{000} &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 :\ x_1 \leq 0, x_2 \leq 0, x_3 \leq 0\}\\
T_{001} &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 :\ x_1 \leq 0, x_2 \leq 0, x_3 \geq 0\}\\
T_{010} &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 :\ x_1 \leq 0, x_2 \geq 0, x_3 \leq 0\}\\
&\vdots\\
T_{111} &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 :\ x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0, x_3 \geq 0\}
\end{align*}
$$
Note that every $T_\xi$ is a convex polyhedron, and that a finite intersection of convex polyhedra is a convex polyhedron.

I noticed that $S_{111}$ and $S_{000}$ were convex polyhedra:
$$
\begin{align*}
S_{111} &= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 :\ x_1 + e^{-1}x_2 + e^{-2}x_3 \leq 1.1\} \cap T_{111},\\
S_{000} &= T_{000},
\end{align*}
$$
and wondered whether all the $S_\xi$'s were convex polyhedra, but was unable either to prove or to disprove this conjecture. However, even if I were able to prove it, it wouldn't in itself solve the question of whether $S$ was a convex polyhedron.

Comment: $S_{011}$ is convex for the same reason as $S_{111}$.

Comment: Are you sure about $S_{111}$? $\arg \max_{u\in(0,1)} x_1 + ux_2 + u^{2}x_3$ is $u=\frac{x_2}{2x_3}$ when this is in $(0,1)$.